# piping to awk hangs

Tags: awk, packet-capture, piping, tshark

I am trying to pipe `tshark` output to `awk`. The tshark command works fine on its own, and when piped to other programs such as `cat`, it works fine (real time printing of output). However, when piped to awk, it hangs and nothing happens.

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -l -f "tcp" -R 'http.request.method=="GET"' -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e 
tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack | awk '{printf("mz -A %s -B %s -tcp \"s=%s sp=%s 
dp=%s\"\n", $2, $1, $5, $4, $3)}'
```

Here is a simplier version:

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -f "tcp" -R 'http.request.method=="GET"' | awk '{print $0}'
```

And to compare, the following works fine (although is not very useful):

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -f "tcp" -R 'http.request.method=="GET"' | cat
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what OS/ version of Linux, please. Also if you system has `unbuffer`, try adding that into the mix. Not a pretty solution, but if you need it work, that might do it. Good luck.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 11.04. I had a go with unbuffer, but no luck- it just hangs.

Comment: Your question is well documented. But ... is it safe to assume that your last example with `cat` also work when all options to tshark i.e. `-T fields ...` are used? It seems that `awk` should have no problem processing the output. Also, what happens when you take `sudo` out of the picture? Good luck.

Comment: cat works fine with all options. I just realised that awk works 'eventually'- after a number of seconds. So I think awk is buffering or something. Due to the nature of the problem, quick response is very important, so I need to find a way to stop awk buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per our previous messages in comments, maybe it will work to force closing the input and emitting a linefeed.

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -f "tcp" -R 'http.request.method=="GET"' ...... \
| {
    awk '{print $0}'
    printf "\n"
  }
```

Note, no pipe between awk and printf.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This greatly increased the response time. It still isnt instant, however, which is weird. I will try using something other than awk. Thanks for you help.

Comment: you may not need the `printf`, but leave the { ... } wrapper. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I have found some partial "solutions" that are not completely portable.
Some of them point to use the fflush() or flush() awk functions or -W interactive option

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

I tried both and none works. So awk is not the appropriate command at all.

A few of them suggest to use gawk but it neither does the trick for me.

*cut* command has the same problem.

My solution: In my case I just needed to put --line-buffered in GREP and not touching awk command but in your case I would try:

```
sed -u
```

with the proper regular expression. For example:

```
sed -u 's_\(.*\)     \(.*\)  \(.*\) DIFF: \(.*\)_\3 \4_'
```

This expression gives you the 3rd and 4th columns separate by TAB (written with ctrl+v and TAB combination). With -u option you get unbuffered output and also you have -l option that gives you line buffered output.

I hope you find this answer useful although is late

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here  https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk (by John1024).

It says:

"You don't see it in real time because, for purposes of efficiency, pipes are buffered. tail -f has to fill up the buffer, typically 4 kB, before the output is passed to awk."

The proposed solutions is to use "unbuffer" or "stdbuf -o0" commands to disable buffering. It worked for me like this:

stdbuf -o0 tshark -i ens192 -f "ip" | awk '{print $0}'